# Jenkins project to GitLab pipeline

Tags: jenkins, gitlab-ci

I'm working on moving from Jenkins to Gitlab CI/CD. I have a Jenkins project that performs some tasks by demand (users can run it any time they want) and it isn't a part of build/deployment. I need to add this task to GitLab CI/CD pipeline but save the opportunity to run only this task manually. What would be the best solution for it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `when` parameter for job definitions [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#when). You can have any number of steps in a pipeline configuration that are kicked off manually, or automatically, and any mix of the two.

For example, a common use case is to build the app, run the tests, then wait for manual input to deploy.

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build:
stage: build
only:
  - tags
script:
  - ./buildScript.sh

deploy_to_prod:
stage: deploy
only:
  - tags
when: manual
script:
  - ./deployScript.sh
```

The `when:manual` means that this job will not start until it someone hits the play button in the Pipeline UI (or a few other ways).